# What factors are limiting form factor of e-ink displays?

Tags: e-ink

Please help me understand what engineering problems are currently limiting e-ink displays from reaching sizes let's say comparable to sizes of standard LCD screens.

I originally thought there are business reasons only (that minimum of folks would buy a display with limited colors and slow response times), but after I found out that even [e-ink manufacturer builds e-ink wall consisting of 7,4" e-ink displays](http://www.the-digital-reader.com/2013/09/29/e-ink-unveils-19-foot-e-ink-screen/#.U1P4A3Zwft0), I started to believe there must be other limiting reasons, too.

In other words: Is there some problem constructing e-ink matrix let's say 25" with FullHD resolution? (although with limited colors, but still suitable for working with text etc.).

Comment: Any news? I've recently seen larger ones, than Kindle DX: [Sony (DPT-S1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTauGe03mQs)(13 inch);
[Onyx Boox Max](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3ZwqIAn-ME)(13 inch)
[Dasung Paper-Like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9DbdaPQyLY) [maybe others exist too, but I havent searched for them]. I know, that DASUNG and Kindle can be used directly as External monitor for PC.

Comment: Surprise.  Many people told on forums, that BenQ has produced monitor: [BenQ  EW2775ZH](https://www.google.com/search?q=BenQ%20EW2775ZH).
That is a very special model for EYE-problematic people (see discussion [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1087420/do-blue-light-filters-actually-reduce-blue-light/1087436#1087436)), which solved eye-sensitive people's problems, who were unable to solve them using E-Ink monitors. I might be interested in that monitor too (if anyone has experience, please comment).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EInk displays use standard TFT processes for the backplane and are fabricated in standard TFT foundries.  A standard LC (Liquid crystal) based display will have the front glass added and be filled with LC where as an EInk display has the micro-capsules added and the front film added.  EInk was very deliberate to ensure that they did not re-invent the wheel to get into production.  Their business model is to sell the front part of the display stack and NOT to manufacture backplanes.

How the panels is driven changes, but this is controlled by the column and row drivers which are relatively easily changed.

That means that the limitation in size is simply one of cost (since you *could* put a EInk stack onto any existing TFT back plane).  The cost is increased either because of direct cost charged by EInk or from poor yield in applying the films to a larger panel (poor yield increases cost, and increases more the later in the process).